# php reservation system

Tags: php, html, database

i m creating a project with php and html use.i would like to create a ticket reservation system for my university.Firstly,the user will choose a date and the number of persons that he wants to reserve tickets.Then,by pressing the next button,he could see the list of the events that are available in the date he checked in the previous step.this list will be static,so i think that i have to create a data base which will have this data and if the users selects ex monday,he could see the data events for monday.Could you please help me do this because i have no big experience with php?i have created the two screens with html and css but now i would like 1st to let me know how to create a data base with my data and secondly how to connect them with my day oprtions!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should find plenty PHP+MySQL tutorials on the web. I guess, first you have to learn what a relational database is and that MySQL is one. Then you have to learn how to connect to MySQL from PHP. As a start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database and PHP's own documentation provides some examples: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at:

[PHP 101: A Simple Seat Reservation System](http://unlikelyteacher.com/2008/04/17/php-101-a-simple-seat-reservation-system/)

Comment: Seriously? did you try the title in google? here is a copy: http://dayg.wordpress.com/2008/04/17/php-101-a-simple-seat-reservation-system/

Comment: yes seriously , the link is broken. You are right, searching for the title does bring up the link you referenced, but that is no guarantee it is the same page as the broken link.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a simple task as you seem to think and explaining it is almost writing the software but I'll try :

1. Create database tables in the database engine of your choice

required tables

table [events] : colums{id Integer,event_date Date,title Varchar,tickets Integer, description Varchar}

/*
 How many tickets are availble for that event, depending on the reservations Count you will show less and less available tickets and eventually you will stop the reservation
*/

table [users]  : columns(id Integer,name Varchar,username Varchar,password Varchar)

table [reservations] : 
  columns(id Integer,
          user_id Integer [foreign key to users],
          event_id Integer [foreign key to events],
          reserved_tickets Integer,
          reserved_at Datetime}

/*
reserved tickets are used if you want a user to be able to reserve more than one ticket per person, for safety reasons you can limit that either by adding a new field in the event table where the event creator can choose how many tickets one person can have or either hardcode it in the code, but this is not so "fancy")
*/

Now you will need a lot of views interfaces:
User management interfaces :

1 List + 1 Add/Edit(administrator) +1 register (user can register them selves, this is optional) = 2 (3)

Event management interfaces:

1 List(administration) + 1 Add/Edit + 1 Event listing (in a calendar or something for reservations) = 3

Reservation management interfaces:

1 List(administration) + 1 Manage (Cancel/confirm the reservation of a user etc) = 2

You will need a login page, maybe a recover password/username, a screen where a user can see his reservation and cancel/confirm whatever.

These should be all html/flash etc eventually mixed or comunicating with code (PHP,JSP,ASP whatever)

Every html should have a control script "behind" it, meaning the actuall code that gets/sets info into/from the database,  this is recommended to be in a separate file then the view (at least) and should be contained in a function or class methods and here are a lot of details to be said, to many.

I recommend that you try and understand CakePHP, it should fit you at this level and anyway to me it seems the simplest framework that one could use and understand empirically.
It's not an easy job as I said, this should take about 12-16 hours to be written from scratch to a professional programmer, and I think it will take you 5 times more even if you use CakePhp. (of course considering a modern interface,approach and functionality otherwise it would take a pro 6 hours at most)

Comment: @Daniel Hanly I see code that works all around but I rarely do see code that is written elegantly and solutions that are conceived with structure and respect for fundamental principles. There is a difference between programming and coding, so that is why I try to explain how to think rather than how to work. Thanks for your support :)